# switching to branch in Eclipse created from atlassian jira

Tags: eclipse, git

I have created a branch from atlassian jira and I can see the branch in the sourcetree, under branches. But when I am going to `Eclipse -> Team -> Switch to -> Other -> Remote Tracking`  I can't see it anywhere.
When I also go to the command line and type

```
git branch -a
```

I don't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure you fetched from remote after having created the new branch in JIRA?

If not, it would explain the remote branch not showing up in your branch -a log.

In that case, just `git fetch` and your local refs of remote branches will be updated.

(And then you'll be able to `git checkout <your_new_branch>` to create the local counterpart and set its upstream in one go)